Clear IIS Redirect at server
I accidentally added a redirect to www.subdomain.domain.com, and the removed it from the web.config.  The server continues to send the 301 Moved Permanently header.
This is an ancient version 8.5 running on Windows Server 2012 R2.  I cannot get it updated. The system is running on Azure.
I've done the following

cleared the browser cache
run in incognito mode in Chrome
tried using Edge
Disable Cache in Chrome Developer Tools
IIS HTTP Response Headers, Expire WebContent Immediately
restart IIS Application
restart IIS Server
disabled IIS Cache and Output Cache
waited several hours
used curl -v to see what the server is sending, it's still sending that 301

Any other suggestions would be appreciated

People probably don’t have any IIS 8.5 machines to reproduce this.

What module are you using to set up IIS redirection? HTTP Redirect module? Or the URL Rewrite module? Have you checked at the server level? It can be found in the IIS Manager, click on the server node and view the corresponding module or find it directly in the IIS configuration file:
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

The redirect was done using the web.config and the URL Rewrite module.  All the other redirects are correct, the one to www. should no longer be there an has been removed.  However it continues to redirect.  I'm suspicious that Azure is caching this.  I know that it is coming from the server as I see it when using curl -v.

@LexLi  I wish I didn't have to deal with a 12 year old system either, but the client won't upgrade.  The server was moved to Azure last fall.

It turned out that the problem was in the CMS, Kentico, which has an option to force WWW.  I turned that off and will retry the move.
